# Render Teaser Image in search block using Twig

Tags: theming, 8, media, search

I am trying to render the teaser image in my search block using twig. For my views page for rending the articles i am using this:

```
  <div class="img-container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/imageObject" data-internal-url="{{ url }}">
    {% block teaser_img_container %}
        {{ content.field_teaser_media }}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
```

And it works very nice but on search block it does not display the image, so I am trying other options like

```
<div class="img-container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/imageObject" data-internal-url="{{ url }}">
  <picture>

   {% block teaser_img_container %}

<img src="{{ file_url(node.field_teaser_media.entity.uri.value) }}" >
 {% endblock %}

     </picture>
  </div>
```

Which should solve my problem, but i still don't see the image i am getting no errors, if i go in my page source the link to image appears but when i inspect the code from I get

```
<img src="/">
```

The link works, but it does not display my image.
Any ideas for fix?

Comment: I see in your code you have `node.field_teaser_media.entity.uri.value` but which node? You could have 200 nodes on your site, so which one? Is there a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) Module

Then go to Manage Display and for your image field and select URL Formatter as your formatter.

then use: `<img src="{{ content.field_teaser_media[0] }}">`

[image]

Comment: I installed the module but can't seem to find url formatter i only have : Entity ID, Rendered Entity, Label, Thumbnail, Data Internal Url. I have tried all of them but to no success

Comment: @DraguAlexandru sorry it's in Manage Display not Manage Fields, my memory was off. Provided pic to clear things up.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response i don't find it because i am not using image field, i am using Entity reference, the type of reference is media and from there i am getting my images.

Comment: Hi,
I get for first code <a href="https://s14.postimg.org/kayrb9e1t/search_example.jpg">Link Here</a>


I get for second try<a href="https://s11.postimg.org/i5z4v30oz/search_example2.jpg">Link Here</a>

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my Manage Display i forgot to put my Teaser Default (Display from where i take my default settings for other teaser displays) to the format Rendered Entity.

Thank you for your help.