# Print image URL with image style

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to print an image URL with an image-style.
This doesn't work, since I don't have a ".value"-value for the image: [How to find image style URL from within twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194749/how-to-find-image-style-url-from-within-twig-template)

Is there anything different on field-templates?

My code in *field--field-images.html*:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <img src="{{ item.content['#url'].uri }}">
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work (results in no filename since .value isn't available:

```
<img src="{{ item.content['#url'].uri.value  | image_style('image_style') }}">
```

This crashes the page:

```
<img src="{{ item.content['#url'].uri | image_style('image_style') }}">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render Teaser Image in search block using Twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214366/render-teaser-image-in-search-block-using-twig)

Comment: Don't do this with template code, configure the proper image style in `Admin > Structure > Content types > (your bundle) > Manage display`

Comment: Just let it render normally and use the display config proper.

Comment: I forgot to say: there's lots of other custom-code in the template file, so I can't use the display configured in the display-settings.

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219039/rendering-an-image-field-in-page-html-twig-with-a-custom-image-style Otherwise the only way I can think of is to use a preprocess to add a variable to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Change the display mode of your field with the image style you want. And it's ok

But If you want do this with a custom module, you can do this:

```
$imageFile = Media::load($media_mid);
$style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('thumbnail');
$imageThumbnailUri = $style->buildUrl($imageFile->get('thumbnail')->entity->getFileUri());
```